# Disable default behavior for all buttons in a Meteor application

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm in the middle of developing multiple Meteor projects where practically every time I create an event for a button, it goes like this:

```
Template.sometemplate.events({
    'click #someid': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // some more code
    }
});
```

Is there a way to disable the default behavior for all buttons in my web application so that I don't have to type `event.preventDefault()` again and again?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do

```
Template.body.events({
    'click button': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```